# Cypher: How to return a node if the relationship doesn't exist?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have User and Building labels for nodes, the relationships are `User-[:HAS_PERMISSION]->Building`

To get all buildings that a user is having permissions to so I use `MATCH (u:User {id: {id}}),(u)-[r:HAS_PERMISSION]->(b:Building) return b`

How can I just return the user in case he exists and there are no relationships? (basically I also want to know if the user exists at all..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think you'll need an `OPTIONAL MATCH`. This query shows all users with or without access to a building.

```
MATCH (u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:HAS_PERMISSION]->(b:Building) 
RETURN u, b
```

Or maybe your requirement is simpler. If you just want all users, there's no need to use pattern matching:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u
```

Comment: thanks, what I was looking for is `MATCH (u:User {id: {id}}) OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:HAS_PERMISSION]->(b:Building) return u, b`, this way I can know when the queried user doesn't exist at all