# Cypher Query - conditionally return a relationship

Tags: cypher, neo4j

I have been trying to figure out how to perform specific query for quite a while, and have been through several attempts to no avail.  Below is an example to illustrate the problem:

There are 2 types of nodes, `user`s and `document`s.  Users can have a relationship type labeled `collaborates_with`, and can be related to documents as `can_edit`, `created`, or have no relationship.

Now what I would like to do is perform a query that will return all documents that fit a set of search criteria (say created within the last week), AND if the document was created by a `collaborator` of a specific user, return that relationship.

To fetch the documents and the creator of each document, the query is pretty straight forward:

```
MATCH (doc:document)<-[rel:created]-(u1:user)
WHERE doc.createddate > TIMESTAMP_FOR_ONE_WEEK_AGO
RETURN doc, u1
```

where `TIMESTAMP_FOR_ONE_WEEK_AGO` is just the unix timestamp corresponding to right now minus 7*24*60*60*1000.

The difficulty comes when trying to conditionally return the relationship with the current user.

I have played with `CASE` statements and `OPTIONAL MATCH`, but nothing seems to get what I'm looking for.  One example of my attempts:

```
MATCH (doc:document)<-[rel:created]-(u1:user)
WHERE doc.createddate > TIMESTAMP_FOR_ONE_WEEK_AGO
WITH doc, u1
MATCH u1-[rel:collaborates_with]-(me:user)
WHERE me.username = MY_USERNAME
RETURN doc, rel
```

This, however, only returns the `document`s that have been created by one of my `collaborator`s.  Instead, I'd like it to return ALL of the `document`s fitting the search, and only return the relationship if it exists.

Has anyone been able to perform something like this?

NOTE: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484598/cypher-how-to-return-a-node-if-the-relationship-doesnt-exist) is similar, but not quite what I'm running into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional Match should do it:

```
MATCH (doc:document)<-[rel:created]-(u1:user)
WHERE doc.createddate > TIMESTAMP_FOR_ONE_WEEK_AGO
WITH doc, u1 //find all docs that satisfy search conditions
OPTIONAL MATCH u1-[rel:collaborates_with]-(me:user) //optionally see if the creator collaborates with me
WHERE me.username = MY_USERNAME
RETURN doc, rel
```